# c#: handling mouse events with ms chart

Tags: c#, .net

i am displaying a line graph on an ms chart using VS2008 c# professional

what i am trying to do is when the user clicks on a datapoint, it will display the entire ROW in the database for that point.

how can i

1. handle the click event
2. display the row for that particular point?

Comment: please to be responding immediately

Comment: Just a *"little"* late... BTW have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552889/c-ms-chart-control-two-questions)

Comment: @dige better late than never. make that into answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

http://pastebin.com/SDxyX1pN

this is just an example, of course if you need to access the DB you need an access logic and so on... but the idea is basically the same.